# Set UINavigationBar title from view contained within UIPageViewContoller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uipageviewcontroller

Here is the problem I am having. I am unable to set the UINavigationBar title for the views I have contained within a UIPageViewController.

The basic architecture of the app is as follows.

1. The root view controller for the app is a UITabBarController, with 5 navigation controllers contained in it.
2. The first Navigation controller, which is the one I am having issues with, contains a page view controller and this page view controller contains a number of UIViewControllers.
3. I want that, when I swipe through each of these view controllers, I can set the title in the UINavigationBar.

I have tried the following:

1. In the UIViewController contained within the page view controller, I have tried  `[self setTitle:@"Title I want"]` - it didn't work.
2. Within the same UIViewController I have also tried `[self.navigationBar.navigationItem setTitle:@"Title I want"]` - this also didn't work.

I also tried setting the title for the View controller and attempted to extract that inside the PageViewControllers delegate method transitionCompleted, but this didn't work either.

I am wondering should I go back to the drawing board, and whether I am going down a rabbit hole with this view layout architecture. Has anyone else encountered this issue and if so, how did you solve it?

Edit: I must also add that I am doing this programatically.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

So, in the end I came up with a way to get this working, albeit not the cleanest solution that I wanted, but suitable for the purpose nonetheless.

1. I created a new class called PageLeafViewController and set up its init method as below. Child view controllers of a page view controller inherit from this. Here is the code.

**Code sample**

```
- (id)initWithIndex:(NSUInteger)index andTitle:(NSString *)navBarTitle; {
    if(self = [super init]) {
        self.index = index;
        self.navBarTitle = navBarTitle;
    }
    return  self;
}
```

2. These can be initialised like so before being added to the UIPageViewController.

**Code sample**

```
ChildViewController *aChildViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] initWithIndex:1 andTitle:@"A Title"];
```

3. You will need to add a UIPageViewControllerDelegate to your interface for your page view controller. This is so you can implement the code for the delegate methods for when your view transition has been completed, and you need to set the title.
4. When the UIPageViewController loads, I grab the first view controller and get its title, setting it to the UINavigationController navigation bar

**Code sample**

```
PageLeafViewController *initialViewController = (PageLeafViewController *)[self viewControllerAtIndex:0];
[self.navigationItem setTitle:initialViewController.navBarTitle];
```

5. When a transition occurs, we set the title again to that of the new child view controller, when the transitioning into view has completed.

**Code sample**

```
- (void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {

    PageLeafViewController *currentLeaf = (PageLeafViewController *)[self.pageViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:currentLeaf.navBarTitle];
}
```

**Note:** The above gets called automatically when a new child view controller has been displayed.

While this is not the most elegant solution it works for now, and I don't think its possible to call a function from within a child view to update the NavigationBar title, unless someone wants to correct me?

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're supposed to set the title on the navigationBar, have you tried `self.navigationController.title = @"Title";` ?

Comment: If you're doing the tabBar programmatically you could set the title when you add the controllers to the TabBar, i think you only need to do `ViewController.title = @"title";` or `VC.view.title`  and then you add it to the controllers array

Comment: The tab bar at the bottom is fine, and I am setting their titles when they are set up. The trick is to figure out how to get the ViewController to tell the navigationbar what title it needs to have, so it can change nicely when the user swipes.